# Set UIButton background colour using name of colour in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uibutton, uicolor

I am getting a json response from server. In that response I received an array of colour names in which colour name is like "Piel / Nude", "Negro / Black".

I would like to set this colour as UIButton's background colour.
I tried this way but app crashes every time:-

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"Black")];
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: can you change your server response having colour code there?

Comment: `performSelector:` is an instance method, and not a class method. `UIColor` cannot simply call an instance method, without an instance.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution #1**
You should have a NSString with for example whiteColor or blueColor and you can convert it in the following way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *colorName=@"Yellow";
NSString *colorStr=[colorName lowercaseString];
colorStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color",colorStr];
UIColor *color=[self getColor:colorStr];
Yourbutton.backgroundColor=color;
```

}

```
-(UIColor *)getColor:(NSString*)colorStr
{
    SEL getColor = NSSelectorFromString(colorStr);
    UIColor *color = nil;
    if ( [UIColor respondsToSelector:getColor] == YES) {

        color = [UIColor performSelector:getColor];
    }
    return color;
}
```

**Solution #2**

```
    NSString *colorStr = @"red";

        NSString *selectorString = [colorStr stringByAppendingString:@"Color"];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
        UIColor *color = [UIColor blackColor];
        if ([UIColor respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            color = [UIColor performSelector:selector];
        }

        Yourbutton.backgroundColor=color;
```

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1**

You can add category for UIColor that will return color by it's name. Right now UIColor has class methods: [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor orangeColor] etc. If you don't like it you can add additional class method declarations:

```
// category of UIColor
+ (UIColor *)Black { return [UIColor blackColor]; }
+ (UIColor *)Green { return [UIColor greenColor]; }
+ (UIColor *)MyBestColor { return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.8 blue:0.1 alpha:1.0]; }
```

In this case your following code will work

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"Black")];
```

**Solution #2**

It's more complex way. If you want to have all colors even those that are not included in UIColor's declaration you can do following:

1) Collect color names and hex (or RGB) values. You can parse data from here [Web Colors](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp) or find other source. Store it in the array in plist file in your project.
2) Add class method that will find color value by it's name. Something like this:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorByName:(NSString *)name {
    // Here you will parse your plist file, find color value by it's name and create a color. 
}
```

To create UIColor from HEX string you may use this project [HexColor](https://github.com/mRs-/HexColors)

Answer (score 0):

[UIColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html)
offers you many default color using `+ (UIColor *)colorNameColor` but not all colors that you may need. So one way to solve this is to crate a category on `UIColor` and declare the class method that you need like `+ (UIColor *)pielColor` or `+ (UIColor *)nudeColor` and use RGB value:

```
+ (UIColor *)pielColor
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.8 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Then use:

```
NSString *methodName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Color", [yourColor lowercaseString]];
[UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(methodName)];
```

Comment: Thanks Gonji for reply, but every time there is new value of colour, So how i can do it?

Comment: This solution assumes that you know all possible color string values that you receive. Then you have to write a method for each color.

Comment: Yes, but its not possible

Answer (score 0):

If there is chance to have many colours, it will be better to update the json response from server. Instead of getting the colour name, get the RGB & Alpha value from the server; like,

**{
  "red" :"0.0",
  "green" : "0.5",
  "blue" :"0.2",
  "alpha" :"1.0"
}**

Then you can use,

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```